# Unable to use Log4j2 AsyncAppender with log4j2.properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have defined `log4j2.properties` as

```
    ...
    appender.async.type = Async
    appender.async.name = async
    appender.async.appenderRefs.type = AppenderRefs
    appender.async.appenderRefs.consoleAppender.type = AppenderRef
    appender.async.appenderRefs.consoleAppender.ref = console

    rootLogger.level = debug
    rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = async
    rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = rolling
```

Exception during runtime:

```
2019-06-28 12:03:27,996 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender for element Async: java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:52)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:180)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:964)

...

2019-06-28 12:03:27,997 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender for element Async: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:234)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:134)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:964)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:904)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:896)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
```

**What is that I'm missing?**

Answer (score 3):

Try below configuration -

```
appender.async.type = Async
appender.async.name = asyncAppender
appender.async.appenderRef.type = AppenderRef
appender.async.appenderRef.ref = consoleAppender
```